# try-catch exception problem, not working a whole exception

Tags: c#, windows, forms, exception, try-catch

this exception work it, to the half, for searching is ok, but from "catch" doesn't pop up a message- "Error in searching", and nothing happen when i type a wrong word which is not in the database, some proposes?

```
try
    {
        Con.Open();
        string query = "Select * from Medicine_tbl where MedName ='" + SearchTb.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand comn = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = comn.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Mednametb.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            Bptb.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            sptb.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            qtytb.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            companycb1.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
        }
        Con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in searching." + ex);
    }   
}
```

I have looking for examples and the word order was the same.

Comment: Does it even catch an Exception from just inputing a wrong word as a filter? That's not necessarily an Exception but more of a No Records Found scenario

Comment: No, nothing catch. How then should pop up a message: "Error in searching", cause i need this for presentation.

Comment: Add a counter-variable that gets incremented during the while-loop. When its 0 (e.g. no records returned) then throw an exception..

Comment: Instead of a catch you should do a null-check of the result from the executed query and if the result is null you can trigger MessageBox.Show("No results found"). With this logic you have implemented you are catching anything that goes wrong with executing the query, which is a valid thing to do but the query can return null without causing an exception so you need to validate the result of the query.

Comment: can you give me a hint, cause i'm a less than junior :)?

Comment: Some unrelated suggestions: a) Do not concat your query strings. Use Parameterized queries. b) move `Con.Close()` into a `finally` block because you want it closed regardless of if an exception happens or not.

Comment: You have gotten a good answer from DevEzro below which is a slightly modified example from the documentation provided by Microsoft. Here's the link where you can read about it and get an better understand of how it works :) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue is being related to the fact that MessageBox.Show is not called when there's nothing to found in the database. Your reader.Read() loop will only execute when there is at least one row in the result. Try this:

```
    try
    {
        Con.Open();
        string query = "Select * from Medicine_tbl where MedName ='" + SearchTb.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand comn = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = comn.ExecuteReader();
    
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Mednametb.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                Bptb.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                sptb.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                qtytb.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                companycb1.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No data found.");
        }
    
        Con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in searching: " + ex.Message);
    }
```

reader.HasRows() checks if there is any rows returned. I made a modification in the catch to show a detailed message of the exception with ex.Message.

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Maybe move that `Con.Close()` to a `finally` just for the sake of minimal "best practices" ... :) Although that's unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: @DevEzro , Thank you it works and  message "No data found" pop up, when i type wrong name.

Comment: @nik-trifonov Thats great man. I'm happy it works for you! Im starting booth in C# and StackOverflow and it would be nice if you check my answer as usefull